# Is there a way to make extentions ordered alphabetically, not based on length?

Tags: python, list, sorting, lambda

I've been using this code to order the extention based on alphabetical order

```
def sort_by_ext(files: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    sort1 = sorted(files, key=lambda x: x[x.rindex("."):-1])
    return sort1
```

When this code uses the input (["x.bit","y.man","format.c"]), format.c is first when I wanted it in position 1. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i did a try by using str.partition() function. as argument the dot "." is used. partition() uses the argument, and divides the string into 3 parts:

- everything before the argument
- the argument itself
- everything after the argument

"this_code.py" => returns a tuple: ("this_code", ".", "py")

```
files = sorted(files, key=lambda x: x.partition(".")[2])
print(files)
```

a second version would be to use the os.path() module, that extracts the extension from a file path:

```
import os
files = sorted(files,key=lambda x: os.path.splitext(x)[1:])
print(files)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
sort1 = sorted(files, key=lambda x: x[x.rindex("."):-1])
```

the `:-1` in the slice cuts off the last character. With a `.c` extension you lose the `c`. Use `None` or leave the position empty.

Demo:

```
inp = ["x.bit","y.man","format.c"]
print([x[x.rindex("."):-1] for x in inp])
#                      ^^
```

prints: `['.bi', '.ma', '.']`